# A directive inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Working on a directive to highlight `<code>` tags that are being outputted by a directive to render `<markdown>` tags.

The problem is that the `<code>` directive is never hit after the `<markdown>` directive runs. However the `<code>` directive runs on code tags that are not outputted from the `<markdown>` directive.

*The Markdown directive*

```
angular.module('App').directive "markdown", ->
  converter = new Showdown.converter()

  scope: true
  restrict: 'E'
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    if attrs.markdown
      scope.$watch attrs.markdown, (newVal) ->
        html = converter.makeHtml(newVal)
        element.html(html)
    else
      redraw = ->
        html = converter.makeHtml(element.text())
        element.html(html)

        #### expecting the code directive to be trigger after this.

      scope.$on "$includeContentLoaded", redraw
      redraw()
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS doesn't know to compile anything from your markdown. There are two ways to get that stuff to compile. One way is using transclusion, but I don't think that will work for your usecase. In your case, you will need to compile the changes from your markdown. To do this, you use Angular's $compile service.

first, inject the `$compile` service into your directive. Then after setting `element.html(html)`, try this: `$compile(element.contents())(scope);`